# How to run the same Role on multiple nodes on Azure?

Tags: azure

I have a simple worker role. I want to paralelize it to run multiple instances (nodes?, machines?).

My question: 
Do I have to multiple deploy it independently to multiple instances (nodes?),

or

is there any way to scale my worker role this way _by_configuration_

Please note this question is *not* about how to synchronize the race conditions when the role will run in parallel. I know this will be a problem and I am going to solve that or that will be an *other* question.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scaling out in Windows Azure is achieved by increasing the number of instances of your worker role.

[It can be done via the Windows Azure Portal or programatically.](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-scale)

[It can also be done in your Service Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156212.aspx) file (set the number of instances).